# PowerBuilder -- How Do I keyword search a drop-down list

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a drop-down list which contains hundreds of items (Strings).

When a user enters a letter-key, the the drop-down selects the first alphabetic string with that letter-key (which is what I want).

The problem is when the users enters in another letter, the drop-down list does not continue the search.

So my question is how can you get these drop-down lists to search more than on letter at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your answer is that there is no simple attribute to set that will produce the functionality you're after; you'll have to leverage code to create it.

If you're using PowerBuilder Foundation Classes (PFC), you can use the DataWindow DropDown Search service, starting with calling u_dw.of_SetDropDownSearch(TRUE). You'll want to look at the PFC help file for more details on how to use the service.

If you don't use PFC, you can still [download the code from Sybase](http://www.sybase.com/developer/codexchange) and adapt it to your application. The object you'll want to start looking at is (pfcdwsrv.pbl)pfc_n_cst_dwsrv_dropdownsearch, and how (pfemain.pbl)u_dw calls the descendant (pfedwsrv.pbl)n_cst_dwsrv_dropdownsearch.

**Very** basically, on the EditChanged event, the service

- gets the text the user has typed (note that your DDDW column has to be editable)
- finds an item in the DropDownDataWindow where the typed text matches the start of the item
- populates the column with the matching item, selecting the text *after* what the user has already typed

There's more to the service that you'll probably want to browse.

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'll try this out either today or tomorrow and report back